# Vue.js : Range slider with two handles

Tags: vue.js, events, event-handling, dom-events, vite

I want to create a vue js components where it contains a range slider of hours with two handles.
I use vue3 + vite.js

I tried this code to implement the components but when I drag one of handles I have an error

**Code :**
this is the template :

```
<template>
      <div>
        <input type="range" ref="rangeInput" v-model="rangeValue" @input="updateRange"/>
        <div class="range-slider">
          <div class="handle" :style="{left: leftHandle + '%'}" @mousedown="startHandleDrag(1)">
            {{ formatHour(rangeValue[0]) }}
          </div>
          <div class="handle" :style="{left: rightHandle + '%'}" @mousedown="startHandleDrag(2)">
            {{ formatHour(rangeValue[1]) }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

and this is the script :

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      rangeValue: [8, 18],
      handleDragging: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    leftHandle() {
      return this.rangeValue[0];
    },
    rightHandle() {
      return this.rangeValue[1];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateRange(event) {
      const value = event.target.value;
      const range = this.rangeValue;
      if (this.handleDragging === 1) {
        range[0] = value[0];
      } else if (this.handleDragging === 2) {
        range[1] = value[1];
      } else {
        range[0] = value[0];
        range[1] = value[1];
      }
      this.rangeValue = range;
    },
    startHandleDrag(handle) {
      this.handleDragging = handle;
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", this.stopHandleDrag);
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.updateRange);
    },
    stopHandleDrag() {
      this.handleDragging = 0;
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", this.stopHandleDrag);
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.updateRange);
    },
    formatHour(value) {
      return value + ":00";
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Error :** 
 
[image]

any ideas to solve it  !!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `startHandleDrag()` and `stopHandleDrag()`, you bind `updateRange()` to the mousemove event:

```
document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.updateRange);
```

There are two issues with that:

1. The target of the `mousemove` event is the element under the cursor. This can be any element, and unless it happens to be an input, it will not have a `value` attribute (and if it does, it will not hold an array). If you really want to use the "mousemove" event, use the cursor coordinates like `pageX` or `pageX`.
2. You bind it as a function pointer (`addEventListener("mousemove", this.updateRange)`), and when called from the listener, `this` will refer to `element.target`. To avoid this, either use an arrow function (`addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => this.updateRange(e))`) or bind `this` (`addEventListener("mousemove", this.updateRange.bind(this))`).

I don't fully understand what you want to do with the handles, but my guess is that adding and removing listeners is a workaround, and you actually want to make them draggable? If so, have a look at the [drag event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/drag_event). Hope that helps!